# htaccess redirect dynamic url with no query string to query string version

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect this:

```
http://domain.com/anotherdomain.com
```

to

```
http://domain.com/subfolder/?website=anotherdomain.com
```

The URL `anotherdomain.com` will be dynamic. It should only detect domains entered after the root domain and not other subfolders. Ex:

**SHOULD REDIRECT**

```
domain.com/anotherdomain.com
```

**SHOULDN'T REDIRECT**

```
domain.com/internet-marketing-services/search-engine-optimization-services/
```

What I've tried:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(/|index.php)?$ /link-building-services/?website=%1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why it is not working is because `%1` is the matching group captured in `RewriteCond` and you aren't capturing anything in your `RewriteCond`. Variables captured in `RewriteRule` are denoted by `$1, $2, $3` etc.

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^.]+\..+)$ /link-building-services/?website=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Gives me a redirect loop. Redirects to `http://www.domain.com/link-building-services/?website=link-building-services/`

Comment: Works for what I want to do but also redirect all other links too. I just need to detect and redirect if a domain is entered, nothing else.

Comment: But how to detent a domain is entered? Since presence of dot is not enough as URL can be `http://domain.com/anotherdomain.com` or `http://domain.com/style.css`

Comment: It doesn't need to be foolproof and 99.9% of the time people won't do that. If they do, we don't care. I modified my question a bit to clarify.